# Confused with Leibniz notation of a derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $f$ is a function and $x$ is function of $t$, how do you find the derivative of $f(x)$ in terms of the derivative of $f(t)$?

With Leibniz' notation this is shown as (using the chain rule) $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$.

So if $x =\ln(t)$ then this would be $$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dt} t$$.

However, I've never quite liked this notation. How do you show this with the initial notation?

Also, the second derivative of the example is (by replacing $\frac{d}{dx}$ with $\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt}$) $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dy}{dt}  t\right) = \frac{dt}{dx}  \left( \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}  t \ + \frac{dy}{dt} \right) = t^2 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+ t \frac{dy}{dt}$$.

This makes even less sense to me.

Could someone show how to do questions of this type with initial notation?

Comment: $x =\ln(t)$  implies $\frac{dt}{dx} =t \ $ 
The product rule gives you the result for
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} =\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt} \left( \frac{dy}{dt}  t\right) = \frac{dt}{dx}  \left( \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}  t \ + \frac{dy}{dt} \right) = t^2 \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+ t \frac{dy}{dt}$$.

Comment: It's one way to see it, or you could just write $\frac{dt}{dx} =(\frac{dx}{dt} )^{-1}=(\frac{1}{t})^{-1} =t $.

Comment: @aflous 
I understood that the product rule was used, but I didn't understand the replacement d/dx with dt/dx d/dt and would prefer to see the first and second derivative with the other notation

Comment: Have you seen why  $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt}$?

Comment: @aflous Frankly, no. If the questions were shown in the other notation I think I would be able to understand.

Comment: btw, your sentence ''If $f$ is a function and $x$ is function of $t$, how do you find the derivative of $f(x)$ in terms of the derivative of $f(t)$''
makes no sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y$ be a function of $x$ which is in turn a function of $t$, then one can write (classical chain rule) :
$$\frac{d}{dt}y(x(t))=x'(t) \cdot y'(x(t))= \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{dy}{dx}$$ 
Now, see that you can rearrange both sides to get 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$

Comment: Thank you. I think I know where my confusion lies: with the meaning of dy/dt. Should it be $y'(t)$ or $[y(x(t))]'$ ?

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is a shorthand for $\frac{d}{dt}y(x(t))$, i.e $[y(x(t))]'$